# Maven Version range: how to set upper limit if breaking changes are not in sight?

Tags: maven, versioning

We are developing multiple dependencies for our applications, one shared project containing code for all applications and one adapter per application for easier (and clearly defined) access from another application. The adapters also have the shared project as dependency. When setting the version of the shared dependency in the adapters, I want to use Maven version ranges, so Maven knows that using a newer version of shared (as the application commands) is no problem.

The problem is, how do I set the upper version limit of the shared dependency? I cannot know when a certain adapter needs to change, so I cannot set the correct upper limit in the moment I deploy the adapter. Deploying an updated artifact the moment I know the upper limit would be bad practice (and not work, as only snapshots get updated) because a released version should not change.

I guess the clean solution would mean that the minor version in the shared project tells that the adapters need to change, so I should set the upper limit to the next minor version. However if there is a slight change in the shared project which affects only one adapter, all the other adapters need an update (newer bug version) with an adjusted upper limit, and all applications need to update all adapters (so Maven does not wrongly resolve the dependency conflict). This would mean a lot of work.

Am I missing a clear solution? Or do I have a flawed understanding of Maven version ranges?

Comment: You should avoid version ranges

Comment: When setting a fixed version I know that Maven should prefer the shared-version set in the application over the transient version. But is this always the case? And what would happen if shared and an adapter are not compatible (because shared had a breaking change for this adapter)? Do I have to look out for exceptions after every update of the shared version?

Comment: As Simon already stated. Do try to avoid version ranges. The question is: Which kind of advantages do see in the usages? Have you experience with version ranges? And why not using fixed version... and using tools like renovate/dependabot or alike.

Comment: If you like to make upgrades to your versions simply make a branch with that...run all your tests.. if everything is green merge it to your main line.. That's the easiest way to go...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: `When setting a fixed version I know that Maven should prefer the shared-version set in the application over the transient version. But is this always the case? ` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise
Lets say my application has two dependencies: shared version 1.00.023, adapter version 1.00.000. Adapter 1.00.000 has shared version 1.00.015 as dependency. Maven should use the shared version 1.00.023, as it should overwrite the transient version 1.00.015. But are there cases where Maven solves this conflict by setting an intermediate version? E.g. when the application wants version 1.01.000, Maven instead uses the highest 1.00-version instead?

Comment: "run all your tests" up to now we are not testing anything unfortunately. But I guess in this scenario I can convince my boss to start using tests on the adapters.

Comment: Define the so called transient version directly in your project and you are save. furthermore I would strongly recommend to use https://semver.org Maven solves by distant from your project to your dependency. Not by version number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid version ranges.

Use `<dependencyManagement>` to fix versions of transitive dependencies.